# What's a great looking responsive multiselect solution?

Tags: multi-selection, bootstrap

I have Q/A section on my Rails 4 site and questions can be tagged with one or many tags. I'm looking for a cool multiselect that I can use for adding tags that will also work on mobile devices. I'm also using bootstrap. I've looked at chosen, selectize and the boostrap-multiselect.

Any ideas for great looking intuitive multiselect solutions?

Comment: How wed are you to the multi select approach? The token-based approach is more popular these days (eg stackexchange)

Comment: Great - but could you suggest some good plugins?

Comment: ok will do, just wanted to make sure it wouldn't be irrelevant to you.

Comment: I saw bootstrap tokenfield which looks interesting. What I really need though is the tokens to be created from a predefined list of tokens. I don't want users to enter in their own tokens - specifically I want users to select tokens from a predefined list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current "state of the art" with tags is to use a token input control:

Here's the StackExchange one:
[image]

Reasons:

- For new users you can configure it (optionally) to drop down a list of initial suggestions.  Or (like SE) you can leave it blank for users to start typing.
- For power users it's faster to type in and complete a set of tags than to scroll through a massive multi-select list.
- It's space saving.
- It allows for new tag creation (also optional), or it can enforce a predefined list of tokens (which sounds like what you're looking for).

If this meets your needs, there are several plugins out there, but one that I have used several times is [jQuery tokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

It just uses Ajax GET or POST/JSON calls so it can be mated to Rails (or any other Ajax-supporting web stack really) easily.  It is configurable with all the options above and more.  It can also be configured to run without Ajax, just using client-side data.

(disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the plugin, its author, etc.)

Comment: Great. Marked as correct answer as this highlighted a new approach which is markedly better than what I was working on.

Comment: Good luck with your app, I see that you're doing Rails in your free time which is awesome